# jxbrowser always downloads with a blank popup

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I am using the jxbrowser from teamdev.

I found a little flaw on downloading items, it will always pop up a blank window with jxbrowser popup as title which break down the user experience here.

**Attempt 1:**

I try to override the download handler class without any popup code. It does not work.

**Attempt 2:**

I also try to override the popup handler that disable popup. It disable all the popup universally and it is not what I want. Plus, it return abstract method error.

```
browser.setPopupHandler(new PopupHandler() {
public PopupContainer handlePopup(PopupParams params) {
    return new PopupContainer() {......}
```

does anyone familiar with jxbrowser? I would like to talk you.

I will setup a bounty shortly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends your JxBrowser version but on JxBrowser 4 (Chromium) you can handle a download with the [DownloadHandler](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/DownloadHandler.html) by adding a [DownloadListener](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/events/DownloadListener.html) and invoke a *JFileChooser* (Swing component) for example.